# How to form Management Hierarchy Formation in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, case, gaps-and-islands

how to form the management hierarchy for below records?

**Input Data:**

| Id | Sub ID | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | NULL | Page Reference | Page Reference |
| 102 | 1 | Page 1 | Page 1 |
| 103 | 2 | Ashok | Ashok |
| 104 | 3 | Kumar | Kumar |
| 105 | 4 | Page 2 | Page 2 |
| 106 | 5 | Arvind | Arvind |
| 107 | 4 | Page 11 | Page 11 |
| 108 | 6 | Gova | Gova |
| 109 | 7 | Gokul | Gokul |
| 110 | 8 | Kannan | Kannan |

I tried with Recursion CTE, I am not able to find exact solution. Need an below format,
Conditions are

```
New Leaf ID --> If Sub ID IS NULL , then it will be 1 , If contains page row, it will be 2, if contains other than that it will be 3.

Page --> Whenever Page row starts, from the next row original information showing for that page. we need to form based on the lead rows.
```

**Output Data:**

| Id | Sub ID | Name | Page | New Leaf ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | NULL | Page Reference |  | 1 |
| 102 | 1 | Page 1 | Page 1 | 2 |
| 103 | 2 | Ashok | Page 1 | 3 |
| 104 | 3 | Kumar | Page 1 | 3 |
| 107 | 4 | Page 11 | Page 11 | 2 |
| 108 | 6 | Gova | Page 11 | 3 |
| 109 | 7 | Gokul | Page 11 | 3 |
| 110 | 8 | Kannan | Page 11 | 3 |
| 105 | 4 | Page 2 | Page 2 | 2 |
| 106 | 5 | Arvind | Page 2 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

The new leaf id is conditional logic. As for the page, it is a bit trickier: it seems like the ordering of the rows defines the dependencies, so basically you want to relate each level 3 leaf to the preceding level 2.

Here is an approach using a window count to identify leafs that belong to the same page:

```
select id, subid, name, 
    case when sub_id is not null
        then max(case when name like 'Page %' then name end) over(order by id) 
    end as page,
    case 
        when subid is null then 1
        when name like 'Page %' then 2
        else 3
    end as new_leaf_id
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when name like 'Page %' then 1 else 0 end) over(order by id) grp
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: If we use order by id, i think it won't work when i used to sort Page column.

Comment: @arvindgova: please give the query a try against your data, and see how it works.

Comment: it is not working. In Page column its showing only 1.